# Basic Relation save

Tags: relations, relatedto, plugin-guestentries

I have two sections:

- Drinks
- Ingredients

I have a relation/entry field set on the drinks. So for example, two entries in the ingredients section are related to a specific drink.

My question:

I have a guest entries form, which submits new ingredients and I want to relate this (or these..) ingredient(s) to the current drink. How would I go about doing this?

Creating the ingredient itself is not the problem. The problem is relating it to the drink.

For example, is there a hidden input where I can pass along a new array?

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You'd use this syntax:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[fieldHandle][]" value="123" />
```

Note the value should be the ID of the entry you want related. There's a handy guide here for the front-end syntax for all of Craft's field types: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input